# The annihilator of an intersection of subspaces in a finite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(V_i)_{i\in I}$ be subspaces of a finite dimensional vector space $V$. Show that $\Big(\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}V_i\Big)^{\circ}=\displaystyle\sum_{i\in I}V_i^{\circ}$ where $V_i^{\circ}$ is the annihilator of $V_i$. It's easy to prove that $\displaystyle\sum_{i\in I}V_i^{\circ}\subseteq\Big(\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}V_i\Big)^{\circ}$  but, I can't prove the reverse inclusion. How to write $f\in \Big(\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}V_i\Big)^{\circ}$ in the sum of each elements in $V_i^{\circ}$ ? Can you one help me with this question.

Answer (score 0):

To prove it you can use the properties of the annihilator: $\forall (V_j)_{j\in I}, \displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}V_i \subseteq V_j$ and, thus, $V_j^{\circ} \subseteq \Big(\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}V_i\Big)^{\circ} \implies \displaystyle\sum_{k\in I}V_k^{\circ} \subseteq \Big(\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}V_i\Big)^{\circ} (*1)$, and properties from the annihilated of a subset of $V^*$:
Let $F$ be a subset of $V^*$, then $ ^\circ F = {x \in V \mid \forall f \in F f(x) = 0} = \displaystyle\bigcap_{f\in F}Ker(f)$ is the annihilated of F. (I don't know if it's called anything else outside of where I'm from, but I couldn't find any information on it, I'm sorry, I suppose it's as easy as to say the annihilator of the annihilator and then using the isometry with $V$ but I don't have the knowledge needed to do that).
Then some properties are easy to prove: $( ^\circ F)^\circ = <F>$ (the other way around too, with a subset of $V$, the annihilated of the annihilator of that subset is equal to the linear hull of F, which is equal to F if it's a subspace) $(*2)$ and given $G$ subset of $F$, $ ^\circ F$ is a subset of  $^\circ G (*3)$. And now we can keep going with the proof:
Let $(H_j)_{j\in J}$ be subspaces of $V$, then $\forall (H_j)_{j\in J}, H_j \subseteq \displaystyle\sum_{k\in J}H_k$, and thus, $\Big{.}^{\circ}\Big(\displaystyle\sum_{k\in I}H_k\Big) \subseteq \ ^{\circ}H_j$. Therefore, $ \Big{.}^{\circ}\Big(\displaystyle\sum_{k\in I}H_k\Big) \subseteq \displaystyle\bigcap_{j\in k} \ ^{\circ}H_j (*4)$.
Then, we know that the annihilator of any subspace of $V$ is a subspace of $V^*$. And thus:
$\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}V_i =_{(*2)} \Big{.}^{\circ} \Big(\Big(\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}V_i \Big)^{\circ} \Big) \subseteq_{(*1\&*3)} \Big{.}^{\circ}\Big(\displaystyle\sum_{i\in I}V_i^{\circ}\Big) \subseteq_{(*4)} \displaystyle\bigcap_{j\in I} \ ^{\circ} (V_i^{\circ}) =_{(*2)} \displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}V_i$. Therefore, since $\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}V_i = \Big{.}^{\circ}\Big(\displaystyle\sum_{i\in I}V_i^{\circ}\Big)$, $\Big(\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}V_i \Big)^{\circ} = \Big{.}^{\circ}\Big(\displaystyle\sum_{i\in I}V_i^{\circ}\Big)^{\circ} = \displaystyle\sum_{i\in I}V_i^{\circ} \Box$

I'll try to prove it in another way, but since you have $\displaystyle\sum_{i\in I}V_i^{\circ}\subseteq\Big(\displaystyle\bigcap_{i\in I}V_i\Big)^{\circ}$ already, you can just use (*3) and (*4) to finish it.